# Prevent the previous event trigger at Page refresh (F5) in ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, postback

In my ASP.net application ,when am entering an data and hitting a button to save the information and its getting saved in the database and then prompt a success message to the user and then i refreshed the page it show a error message like the below!

[Warning message details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTOUY.png)

can anyone help for this to prevent this. Thanks in advance/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Avoid form Re-Submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759572/avoid-form-re-submit)

Answer (score 1):

After postback you need to redirect to the same page