# How to prevent postback when button is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I have a code that save file in database. I have this function in my code behind:

```
protected void AttachFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtFile.HasFile)
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(txtFile.PostedFile.FileName);
            string contentType = txtFile.PostedFile.ContentType;

            using (Stream fs = txtFile.PostedFile.InputStream)
            {
                using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
                {
                    Random ran = new Random();

                    byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
                    NewRequestService newrequest = new NewRequestService();

                    string temp_id = "";
                    temp_id = ran.Next(100000, 999999).ToString();

                    saveAttachFile(filename, contentType, bytes, temp_id);
                    hdnAttachID.Value = temp_id;
                    lblAttach.InnerHtml = msg;
                }
            }

        }
        else { lblAttach.InnerHtml = "\"Please browse the file to attach.\""; }

    }
```

And here's my HTML:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAttached" runat="server" Text="Attach File" OnClick="AttachFile" />
<asp:FileUpload ID="txtFile" size="46" runat="server" />
```

By simply clicking `"Attach File"` button, it will call the code behind function and save the file browse by the user. It work just fine but when I refresh the page it goes to the function again and repeat the saving process ending with duplicate of records. How can I avoid this to happend?

Some I tried are:

1. Adding `if (!IsPostBack) {}` condition.
2. Adding `onClientClick="return false"` attribute in my button.

But it did not solve the problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `if (!IsPostBack) {}` and `onClientClick="return false"` both function will work what they are suppose to do. But refreshing the page is a different thing. Its not a postback event. It will load the whole page.

Comment: try using update panel

Comment: you can redirect to same page after inserting data .  
Response.Redirect(same page path);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this technique to prevent the double trigger on your control events after refreshing:

1. Add this code to your code behind page `PreRender` event

   ```
   protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       ViewState["CheckRefresh"] = Session["CheckRefresh"];
   }
   ```
2. Add this line on your `Page_Load` event.

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     if (!IsPostBack)
     {
       Session["CheckRefresh"] = Server.UrlDecode(System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
       // rest of your code here ...
     }
   }
   ```
3. On your controls event, like your button click or any other control that you want to prevent this on page refresh check these condition first.

   ```
   protected void AttachFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (Session["CheckRefresh"].ToString() == ViewState["CheckRefresh"].ToString())
       {
          // your code starts here ..

          if (txtFile.HasFile)
          {
             //...
          }

          // your code ends here ..

          Session["CheckRefresh"] = Server.UrlDecode(System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
       }
   }
   ```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Post/Redirect/Get (PRG)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern to overcome this. You can see a similar question answered here.
[how to prevent data from sending if user press F5 or refresh in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353461/how-to-prevent-data-from-sending-if-user-press-f5-or-refresh-in-asp-net)